# Is there any Motorola Emulator for MC70 Device?

Tags: windows-mobile, sdk, motorola

I need to develop a mobile application for Motorola MC70 Device.

And i was wondering how to test BarCode Reading, and other hardware related stuff.

is there an emulator for this? or do i need the actual phone?

in Addition, if any of you have worked with this device before, what recommendations and link can you send to me?

Your help will be appreciated. Is kind of hard to find info on this subject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think Motorola has an emulator for it, and to be honest, I wouldn't use one anyway.  Emulated hardware is difficult to get working really well and it never precludes testing with read hardware anyway.

What I'd do is separate out the hardware-specific functionality into interface-based services.  Then you can create two versions of the service - one for the real hardware and one for simulation. You can then write a simulation service to run on any emulator or any piece of available hardware and test your app behavior when that service presents data.

At that point you can do all the work you need except that final bit of actual hardware integration, and you have an infrastructure that really facilitates unit and automated testing of your application.